# asp.net dropdown list codes reuse across multiple pages

Tags: asp.net

I have done some classic ASP, but really new to ASP.NET, so please give me some steps if you can.

What I try to do is reuse the same dropdown list codes across multiple forms on different pages.

I have the Form1.aspx page, and it has this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Vendor" runat="server" 
AutoPostBack="True" 
onselectedindexchanged="ddlVendor_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Then the code behind file Form1.aspx.cs page has this to build the list for Vendor dropdown box.

```
private void FillVendor()
{
    string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConn);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT VendorID, VendoName FROM Vendor";
    DataSet objDs = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
    con.Open();
    dAdapter.Fill(objDs);
    con.Close();
    if (objDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Vendor.DataSource = objDs.Tables[0];
        Vendor.DataTextField = "VendorName";
        Vendor.DataValueField = "VendorID";
        Vendor.DataBind();
        Vendor.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");
    }
    else
    {
        lblMsg.Text = "No Vendor found";
    }


}
```

Lets say if I have another form2.aspx page and form2.aspx.cs page.  This page will use the same dropdown list like form1.aspx page.  I don't want to re-write the same codes again in form2.aspx and form2.aspx.cs.  Is there a better way to re-use these codes behind accross multiple pages?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Develop it as a custom control and reuse it that way?

Comment: Yes - extract the reusable code into a [User Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26db8ysc(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create a user control for your custom dropdown list
2. You can write method accepting DropdownList, label as an arguments and then set properties.